# Reading Nested dictionary with Tuple key,values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested, tuples

I am trying to read/ print out information from a nested dictionary.
The nested dictionary has key,values which are tuples/lists and for each element in the tuple, my code is supposed to print out the data in the dictionaries under it once

The dictionary is as follows

```
self.default_value=[1,2]
self.standardized_dictionary = { "something1" :{tuple(self.default_value) : {"something2": (13,14),
           "something3":tuple(self.default_value),
           "something4":tuple(self.default_value),
           "something5":{tuple(self.default_value):{"something6":tuple(self.default_value),
         "something7":tuple(self.default_value),
         "something8": {tuple(self.default_value): {"something9":{tuple(self.default_value):{"something10":tuple(self.default_value),
         "something11":{tuple(self.default_value):{"something12":tuple(self.default_value)}},
         "something13":{tuple(self.default_value):{"something14":tuple(self.default_value)}},
         "something15":{tuple(self.default_value):{"something16":tuple(self.default_value)}}}},                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
         "something17":{tuple(self.default_value):{"something18":tuple(self.default_value),            
         "something19":tuple(self.default_value)  ,                                                                                                                     
         "something20":{tuple(self.default_value):{"something21":tuple(tuple(self.default_value)),                                                                                                                      
         "something22":tuple(self.default_value) ,                                                                                      
         "something23":tuple(self.default_value)}},                                                                                       
         "something24":tuple(self.default_value),                                                                                                                        
         "something25":tuple(self.default_value),                                                                                                                      
         "something26":tuple(self.default_value)}}}}}}}}}
```

The output that I am expecting should look something like this , but If i am just able to get the ouput without the structure, is alright.

```
• Something1 : 1
    ○ Something2 :13
    ○ Something3 :1 
    ○ Something4 :1
    ○ Something5 :1
        § Something6 :1
        § Something7 :1
        § Something8 :1
            □ Something9 :1
                ® Something10 :1
                ® Something11 :1
                    ◊ Something12 :1
                    ◊ Something12 :2
                ® Something13 :1
                    ◊ Something14 :1
                    ◊ Soemthing14: 2
                    ◊ Something14 :3
                ® Something15 :1
                    ◊ Something16 :1
            □ Something17 :1
                ® Something18:1
                ® Something19:1
                ® Something20:1
                    ◊ Something21:1
                    ◊ Something22:1
                    ◊ Something23:1
                ® Something24:1
                ® Something25:1
                ® Something26:1
• Something1 : 2
    ○ Something2 :14
    ○ Something3 :2 
    ○ Something4 :2
    ○ Something5 :2
        § Something6 :2
        § Something7 :2
        § Something8 :2
            □ Something9 :2
                ® Something10 :2
                ® Something11 :2
                    ◊ Something12 :3
                    ◊ Something12 :4
                ® Something13 :2
                    ◊ Something14 :4
                    ◊ Soemthing14: 5
                    ◊ Something14 :6
                ® Something15 :2
                    ◊ Something16 :2
            □ Something17 :2
                ® Something18:2
                ® Something19:2
                ® Something20:2
                    ◊ Something21:2
                    ◊ Something22:2
                    ◊ Something23:2
                ® Something24:2
                ® Something25:2
                ® Something26:2
```

My present code looks like this -

```
class Output_control():

def __init__(self):
        self.default_value=[1,2]
        self.standardized_dictionary = { "something1" :{tuple(self.default_value) : {"something2": (13,14),
           "something3":tuple(self.default_value),
           "something4":tuple(self.default_value),
           "something5":{tuple(self.default_value):{"something6":tuple(self.default_value),
         "something7":tuple(self.default_value),
         "something8": {tuple(self.default_value): {"something9":{tuple(self.default_value):{"something10":tuple(self.default_value),
         "something11":{tuple(self.default_value):{"something12":tuple(self.default_value)}},
         "something13":{tuple(self.default_value):{"something14":tuple(self.default_value)}},
         "something15":{tuple(self.default_value):{"something16":tuple(self.default_value)}}}},                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
         "something17":{tuple(self.default_value):{"something18":tuple(self.default_value),            
         "something19":tuple(self.default_value)  ,                                                                                                                     
         "something20":{tuple(self.default_value):{"something21":tuple(tuple(self.default_value)),                                                                                                                      
         "something22":tuple(self.default_value) ,                                                                                      
         "something23":tuple(self.default_value)}},                                                                                       
         "something24":tuple(self.default_value),                                                                                                                        
         "something25":tuple(self.default_value),                                                                                                                      
         "something26":tuple(self.default_value)}}}}}}}}}
        self.ExpDict=self.standardized_dictionary
        self.prestring = 0
        self.counter=0
        self.controlCounter=0
        self.previousentry=[]
        self.anotherpreviousentry=[]
        self.anothercounter=0

 def myprint(self,d):
        for k, v in d.items():
            self.anothercounter+=1
            self.anotherpreviousentry.append(k)

            if isinstance(v, dict):
                print("FIELD",k, " : ", )
                for key,val in v.items():
                    self.previousentry.append(k)
                    self.controlCounter+=1

                    if len(self.previousentry)!=1:  
                        if self.previousentry[self.controlCounter-2]!=self.previousentry[self.controlCounter-1]:    
                            self.counter=0
 
                    if  isinstance(key,tuple):
                        for item in key :
                            self.counter+=1
                            print('%10s' % 'number:', item)
                            self.myprint(val)
            else:
                for item1 in v:
                    print("    {0} : {1}".format(k, item1) ) 
                    if self.anotherpreviousentry[self.anothercounter-2]==self.anotherpreviousentry[self.anothercounter-1]:
                        self.counter-=1

printingstuff = Output_control()
printingstuff.main()
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your desired output. Where did the `(13, 14)` go from `something2` in the input, and where are the `1 2 3` and `4 5 6` coming from for `something14`?

Comment: Ahh so i was giving an example of how that final level of the dictionary could have a tuple of tuples as its Value. A little confusing maybe, i could change it if it would help.
Ive changed the expected output meanwhile to reflect the ```(13,14)```  inputs of ```something2```

Comment: That still does not explain why `something14` appears 6 times.

Comment: @AngusL'Herrou For example say i am running a test cycle on some hardware. 
``` something1``` stores the test cycle number. ``` something14``` could be a trigger on that test cycle and it stores the timestamps of those triggers .and it was pushed 3 times. in each of the test cycles. Hence you see it 6 times. For simplicity sake i could remove that and figure it out on my own, but I kept that in there for now to simulate as closely as possible the problem I have. What would you recommend i change to make it seem a bit more straightforward otherwise?